# 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset' al ingresar dato en el Panel admin

Tags: python, django

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que yo introduzco datos en Data insts, me aparece el siguiente error:

> 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Estoy haciendo una página web para alojamiento de mascotas y todo iba bien hasta que apareció este error y no sé qué significa. Dice sobre el tiempo de Zona, pero no sé cómo solucionarlo, lo cual no entiendo mucho, y justo cuando pasa este error, me ocurre lo mismo con **Service Providerss**.

Antes de ingresar cualquier dato no me genera el error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner    
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 686, in wrapper   
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view  
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py", line 62, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py", line 242, in inner       
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 46, in _wrapper        
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py", line 133, in _wrapped_view  
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py", line 2068, in changelist_view
    "selection_note": _("0 of %(cnt)s selected") % {"cnt": len(cl.result_list)},
                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 376, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1867, in _fetch_all     
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 117, in __iter__        
    for row in compiler.results_iter(results):
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1336, in apply_converters
    value = converter(value, expression, connection)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\operations.py", line 331, in convert_datetimefield_value
    value = timezone.make_aware(value, self.connection.timezone)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 290, in make_aware       
    if is_aware(value):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Johan Marrugo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 256, in is_aware
    return value.utcoffset() is not None
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

Les presento mi código en modelos:

```
from django.db import models


#AQUI HICIMOS UN INSPECTDB DE DJANGO PARA USAR LOS MODELOS YA PREDETERMINADO DE EL

class AuthGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group'


class AuthGroupPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey('AuthPermission', models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_group_permissions'
        unique_together = (('group', 'permission'),)


class AuthPermission(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING)
    codename = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_permission'
        unique_together = (('content_type', 'codename'),)


class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True,blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.IntegerField()
    is_active = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} '.format(self.username, self.first_name)
        
    


class AuthUserGroups(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    group = models.ForeignKey(AuthGroup, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_groups'
        unique_together = (('user', 'group'),)


class AuthUserUserPermissions(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)
    permission = models.ForeignKey(AuthPermission, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user_user_permissions'
        unique_together = (('user', 'permission'),)


class DjangoAdminLog(models.Model):
    action_time = models.DateTimeField()
    object_id = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    object_repr = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    action_flag = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    change_message = models.TextField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey('DjangoContentType', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_admin_log'


class DjangoContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_content_type'
        unique_together = (('app_label', 'model'),)


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_migrations'


class DjangoSession(models.Model):
    session_key = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=40)
    session_data = models.TextField()
    expire_date = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'django_session'


#A PARTIR DE AQUI CREAMOS NOISOTROS LOSMODELOS

#DATOS DE USUARIOS BASICOS
class DataUser(models.Model):
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    create_data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    type_house = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    preference = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    nationaty = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    cedula = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    commet = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    fk_user = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_user', blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True) # Field name made lowercase.
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, upload_to= 'perfil')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'data_user'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.fk_user, self.cedula, self.city, self.preference, self.type_house)

        

#DATOS DE INSTITUIONES PUBLICAS O PRIVADAS
class DataInst(models.Model):
    name_inst = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=300)
    phone = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    type_rif = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)
    rif = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_open = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    data_close = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    red_media = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    bibliografia = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, upload_to= 'data_inst')
    
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    create_data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    fk_inst = models.ForeignKey(AuthUser, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_inst', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'data_inst'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {} {}'.format(self.name_inst, self.email, self.rif, self.city)
```

Modelos de servicios:

```
from django.db import models

from app_loginR_django.models import DataInst

# Create your models here.

class ServiceProviderTypes(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'service_provider_types'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.name, self.key)
        
        
        
class ServiceProviders(models.Model):
    fk_institution = models.ForeignKey(DataInst, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_institution', blank=True, null=True)
    fk_service_provider_types = models.ForeignKey(ServiceProviderTypes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_service_provider_types', blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    days = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, upload_to= 'service_providers')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'service_providers'
        
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.name, self.days, self.create_date)
```

Aquí les presento mi admin de login:

```
    from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
# Aqui visualizamos en el panel de administracion lo que hemos hecho por aplicacion 

from app_loginR_django.models import DataUser,DataInst

    
    

    
class DataUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display =("fk_user", "cedula", "city", "preference", "type_house" )
    search_fields = ["cedula", "city", "preference" ]
    list_filter =("cedula",  "preference", "city", "type_house", "fk_user")
    


admin.site.register(DataUser, DataUserAdmin)
admin.site.register(DataInst)
```

Aquí de mi jornadas:

```
from django.urls import path
from app_jornadas_django import views

urlpatterns = [  
    
    path("", views.viewJornadas, name = "Jornadas"),
    #path("modalJornada", views.viewJornadas, name= "modalJornada"),
    path("instituto", views.viewInsti, name= "instituto")
    #path('authpets/', APIpets.as_view(), name = 'lista_mascotas' )
    

]
```

Aquí mis URL de mi aplicación Login:

```
from django.urls import path
from app_loginR_django import views


urlpatterns = [

    path("", views.ViewSLogin, name="Login"),
    path("register", views.ViewRegister, name="Register"),
    path("userperfil", views.UserProfile, name="userperfil"),
    path("logout", views.cerrarSession, name="logout"),


]
```

Aquí de mis servicios o jornadas:

```
from django.urls import path
from app_jornadas_django import views

urlpatterns = [  
    
    path("", views.viewJornadas, name = "Jornadas"),
    #path("modalJornada", views.viewJornadas, name= "modalJornada"),
    path("instituto", views.viewInsti, name= "instituto")
    #path('authpets/', APIpets.as_view(), name = 'lista_mascotas' )
    

]
```

Comment: "Dice sobre el tiempo de Zona": ¿qué dice _exactamente_ el error? Pulsa en [edit] y ponlo en la pregunta.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que alguno de los campos que crees que son de tipo fecha, en realidad están en la base de datos con el tipo texto. No tengo mucha experiencia con django, pero no te recomiendo el uso de tablas no-gestionadas para la autentificación de usuarios.

Comment: El error lo puse en pantalla con una imagen y lo que me sale de consola. es este: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset' pero los detalles estan arriba, he solucionado haciendo esto: en settings cambien un valor de true a false: USE_TZ = False
pero no se que tan importante sea.

Comment: sobre los campos, eso pense y los cambie, pero nada de nada, es raro. todo iba bien pero hoy dio ese error, ya que esa base de datos, me ha funcionado ya 4 meses y hoy dio ese error. ¿Alguna idea? me tiene super curioso jaja